# How pass multiple attributes to View on Button Click?

Tags: django, post, button

I am using Django as my web Framework.
On my website there is a view that shows all "projects" of a user. Here the user has the possibility to leave the project or to add a user to the project.

When a user presses a button, I want the respective action to be executed.
To check if the share or leave button has been pressed i have added a button in my button:

```
<form method="POST">
    <button name="leave_project" type="submit" ...>...</button>
</form>
```

and can then check in the views:

```
if 'leave_project' in request.POST:
```

However, now I still need the ID of the project that was clicked on.
How can I also pass the ID?

I know that I could solve the problem by adding a new view with the ID in the url. But then the page would have to be reloaded which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Your each project has two buttons :

1. leave
2. add

so, in your form

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'your_url_name' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="pk" value="{{project.id}}"/>
    <button name="action" value="leave" type="submit">...</button>
    <button name="action" value="add" type="submit">...</button>
</form>
```

Now

In your view

```
def your_view(request):
    project_id = request.POST['pk']
    if request.POST['action'] == "leave":
       #do whatever
    if request.POST['action'] == "add":
       #do whatever
```